# undefined method `have_content' using Cucumber / Capybara / sinatra

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, sinatra, capybara

I'm trying to validate the start of an initial page for a Sinatra application but am struggling to get the testing framework working. Googling around suggests I add cucumber/rails/rspec or similar, but do I really need to add rails related libraries when not using Rails?

Here's my Gemfile

```
source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra', '1.3.1'
gem 'json', '1.6.3'


group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.7.0'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.3'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rack-test', '0.6.1'
end
```

and my steps:

```
Given /^a room needs to be surveyed$/ do

end

When /^I start a survey$/ do
  survey_tool.start_a_survey
end

Then /^the system will prompt me for a survey summary$/ do
  survey_tool.validate_start_a_survey_page
end
```

and my world extensions

```
module KnowsTheUserInterface
  class UserInterface
    include Capybara::DSL

    def start_a_survey()
      visit '/start_a_survey'
    end

    def validate_start_a_survey_page ()
      page.should have_content('Welcome')
    end
  end
  def survey_tool
     @survey_tool ||=UserInterface.new
  end

end

World(KnowsTheUserInterface)
```

and my env

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'lib', 'survey_tool')

require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application
Sinatra::Application.set :environment, :test
```

The error I receive is

Scenario: Start a survey                              # features/start_a_survey.feature:4
    Given a room needs to be surveyed                   # features/step_definitions/start_a_survey_steps.rb:1
    When I start a survey                               # features/step_definitions/start_a_survey_steps.rb:5
    Then the system will prompt me for a survey summary # features/step_definitions/start_a_survey_steps.rb:9
      undefined method `have_content' for #<KnowsTheUserInterface::UserInterface:0x007f910465fc38> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/support/world_extensions.rb:10:in`validate_start_a_survey_page'
      ./features/step_definitions/start_a_survey_steps.rb:10:in `/^the system will prompt me for a survey summary$/'
      features/start_a_survey.feature:7:in`Then the system will prompt me for a survey summary'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you do not have the rspec expectations included. A Capybara node has a `has_content?` method.

It is the rspec expectation that, when given 'have_content' as an argument, calls 'has_content?' on the target.

So try adding 'rspec-expectations' to your Gemfile, and adding `require 'rspec/expectations'` into your module.